# Access query with departments but some inside of another

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

Here is the problem:
There is tools that are owned by departments. So we can create a query that shows up in a report filtered by department. The problem here is when department B,C,D are "inside" A. So when I want a report for department A I want A,B,C and D. The best I could do for now is creating multiple queries for each case. Basically I did one for B and one for C and D. Then I did one for A where I put a where condition saying "where id field of department is B or C or D". But I think this is not the correct way do to because I'm building a form to make generated reports.
So the major problem here is make a department inside another inside another. I thought making more than one table for department BUT this makes it not scalable.
How can I do?

Comment: You must have a table that defines that B,C,D are inside A? Join to that table. Better still post the tables and what you've tried so far.

Comment: To post tables, prepare the sample data in Excel or Access, then copy to http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html